# Problem using mysql++ library

Tags: c++, mysql, select, mysql++

I've read the tutorial at, and I generally get how that works:
http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#simple

I am trying to build this mysql++ code, and I'm getting an error:

```
std::ostringstream query3;
query3<<"select pipe_id from pipe where version_id='"<<id<<"'";
std::storeQueryResult ares=query3.store();

for(size_t i=0;i<ares.num_rows();i++)   
   cout<<ares[i]["version_id"]<<ares[i]["pipe_id"]<<std::endl;

mysql_query(&mysql,query3.str().c_str());
```

The error is that `store` is not a member of `ostringstream`.  I'm not sure how to correct the problem.

---

Hi Merlyn,

Thanks for the code and looking at my problem.

I tried the above code but again I am getting the error

error: request for member 'query' in 'connection' which is non-class type 'MYSQL*'

on this line of code

```
// Construct a query object with the query string mysqlpp::Query query = 
connection.query(query_string);
```

kindly help where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please edit your code so that it looks like real c++ code.

Comment: Please try to be clearer about what you want to do and what your actual problem is.

Comment: Edited the question based on his previous questions.

Comment: There is no `std::storeQueryResult` and there is no `std::ostringstream::store()`.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: Sounds like an answer to me ;)

Comment: Hi, sandeep.  You're new, but seem to be having problems understanding how StackOverflow works.  Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  StackOverflow is not a forum; do not answer your own question when replying to someone.  When you reach 50 rep, you can leave comments.  Until then, please edit your answer to add more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have to use a mysql++ query object to execute a query, not an ostringstream.  The ostringstream just lets you build the query string, but won't let you perform the query.

There is a tutorial that shows basic usage at:
http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#simple

To get from your code to a query that works, you need to take your dynamic query, turn it into a string, and use it to construct the mysql++ query object.

```
// todo: create the connection here

// Construct the query string.  You were already doing this in your code
std::ostringstream query_builder;
query_builder << "select pipe_id from pipe where version_id='" << id << "'";

// Convert the ostringstream to a string
std::string query_string = query_builder.str();

// Construct a query object with the query string
mysqlpp::Query query = connection.query(query_string);

// Perform the query
mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult result = query.store();
for(size_t i = 0; i < result.num_rows(); i++)
   std::cout << result[i]["version_id"] << result[i]["pipe_id"] << std::endl;
```

Comment: If `connection.query(query_string)` doesn't work, you can try `connection.query(query_string.c_str())` instead.